# Fragment not attached to a context; requireContext() in ArrayAdapter, Async Task

Tags: android, kotlin

Can't figure out what I have to do, to create a ListView by using ArrayAdapter. So far here's my code:

```
class GetSongListAsync(private val activity: LastSongs) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Array<String>>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): Array<String> {
            val url =
                URL("https://vivalaresistance.ru/radio/stuff/vlrradiobot.php?type=getPlaylist")
            val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            connection.requestMethod = "GET"
            connection.connect()

            val songList = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(connection.inputStream, "windows-1251"))

            connection.disconnect()
            return songList
                .readText()
                .replace("и&#774;", "й")
                .replace("И&#774;", "Й")
                .split("\n").dropLast(1).toTypedArray()
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Array<String>) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            val list = LastSongs().view?.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list)
            val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(activity.requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result)
            list?.adapter = arrayAdapter
        }
    }
```

Right now the app is crashing everytime I'm switching to `LastSongs` fragment and I'm getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment LastSongs{79211d9} (2b2b2711-f9a8-4352-92ec-55a25a224ea0) not attached to a context.`

If I comment three lines and try to Log the `result`, everything is fine. The `result` is exactly what i need.

```
override fun onPostExecute(result: Array<String>) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            Log.d("Songs", result.joinToString("; "))
            // val list = LastSongs().view?.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list)
            // val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(activity.requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result)
            // list?.adapter = arrayAdapter
        }
```

So far I find, that the problem is with `activity.requireContext()`. I'm making a mistake that I can't understand. How can I get the right context here?

Comment: Is your view from Activity and you are trying to use in Fragment?

Comment: No, view is part of fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. I added two parameters to my `GetSongListAsync` class: one for context and one for list. Now it looks like this:

```
class GetSongListAsync(private val context: Context, private val list: ListView) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Array<String>>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): Array<String> {
            *stuff*
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Array<String>) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result)
            list.adapter = arrayAdapter
        }
    }
```

Now every time I'm calling this class from view, I have to add this parameters.

```
    val reqCon = requireContext()
    val swipe: SwipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipe)
    val list = view.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list)

    swipe.setOnRefreshListener {
        GetSongListAsync(reqCon, list).execute()
        swipe.isRefreshing = false
    }
```

Maybe not the best way to do it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code isn't providing the correct params, if you are using the `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` you can simply call `requireContext() or requireActivity()`

````
private View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
   return view;
}

val list = view?.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list)
val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, counties)```


Please check your imports.
````

Comment: Yes, I'm using `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`. I tried to call just `requireContext()`, but I get an error: `No value passed for parameter 'p0'`